# Async DataTable Call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

Here is what I have so far... `FillDataTable()` works just fine but I'm running into issues because I have synchronous code and lots of calls to make back to back. Many of them are ready to run before the proceeding one finishes. Trying to convert this to `async/await`. I copied `FillAsync()` from other examples I had seen, so it might be Franken-code.

```
public static DataTable FillDataTable(string sql, Database _db) {
           using (OleDbConnection conn = NewConnectionFromGivenDB(_db)) {
                  conn.Open();
                  using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn)) {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(comm)) {
                                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
                                    da.Fill(dt);
                                }
                                conn.Close();
                                return dt;
                         }
                   }
           }
    }

    public static async Task<DataTable> FillAsync(string sql, Database _db) {
           return await Task.Run(() => { return FillDataTable(sql, _db); });
    }
```

When I call the following in an `async` method, the code never returns.

```
DataTable dt = await FillAsync(sql, Database.Oracle);
```

Can anyone see what is wrong or give me some suggestions for a better way forward?

Comment: In what context are you running the application? WPF/ASP.NET/Forms, things like that?

Comment: @Caramiriel application is all WPF

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Result` or `Wait` on some task in code not shown here. This causes the classic ASP.NET (or WinForms/WPF) deadlock. Use await for all waits.

> Many of them are ready to run before the proceeding one finishes

Are you trying to run things in parallel? Your code does not do that. await does not start tasks; it waits for tasks that are already running. It *ends* parallelism.

Comment: You were right, but it was very confusing to me to understand why... the call above this was using .Result().